# How to make \section items numbers show as Roman Numerals like I II III IV..?

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, numbering

And how to make them show as roman numerals in TOC?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change the representation of the corresponding counter (`section`, in this case) by adding to the preamble:

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
```

EDIT: this redefinition will probably require increasing the space allowed for typesetting section numbers in the ToC; this can be done, for example, with the help of the [tocloft](https://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft?lang=en) package by adding the following lines to the preamble:

```
\usepackage{tocloft} 
\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{1.5cm}
```

Comment: and how to set space between roman numeral and item name in TOC and in general for sections?

Comment: Well, you can make `\thesection` do anything you want, so `\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}\quad}` would throw a quad space in. However, if you are realy getting into section styling, it is better to use a package like [titlesec](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) or a document class like [memoir](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) that really gives you fine control over such things.

Comment: quad  helps in main article but does not help in \tableofcontents =(

Comment: @Kabumbus: using the `tocloft` package you can add to the preamble: `\usepackage{tocloft}` and `\addtolength{\cftsecnumwidth}{1cm}`

Comment: @Sharpie: Never define `\thesection` with a `\quad`. Euqation numbers, cross reference whould also use `\thesection`.

Comment: @Leo Personally, I would never add a `\quad` to that command in an actual document. I did so for the purpose of creating a very visible example of how redefining `\thesection` can contain any arbitrary command. @Kabumbus You have to typeset a document twice for changes to show up in the table of contents.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your packages. Maybe you are loading `tocstyle` or `tocloft`. Normally you can redefine `l@section`. See also `\@dottedtocline`.